# Mocking a JPA repository with Mockito in Java does not get invoked

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm writing unit tests for a Service Implementation that uses JPA repo - MessageRepository, which returns a "Wanted but not invoked: Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock" when I try to verify if it's being invoked. I've extracted parts of code to simplify problem explanation.

**Service Implementation:**

```
public class MessageServiceImpl {

  private final MessageRepository messageRepository;

  public MessageServiceImpl(MessageRepository messageRepository) {
    this.messageRepository = messageRepository;
  }

  public Message create(){
    Message result;        
    //some operations...
    Message message = new Message();
    message.setId(2L);
    message.setName("123231231");
    ...

    result = save(message);
    return  result;
  }

  public Message save(Message message){
    Message result = messageRepository.save(message); // returns a null when I debug while Testing
    return result;
  }

}
```

**Unit Test Class**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MessageServiceImplUnitTest {

@Mock
MessageRepository messageRepository;

@Mock
OtherService otherService; // not a jpa repo but uses one in its implementation and works just as expected

@InjectMocks
MessageServiceImpl messageService;

Message message;

@Before
public void setup() {

    initMocks(this);
    message = new Message();
    message.setId(1L);
    message.setMessageDirection(MessageDirection.OUT);
}


// Unit Test for create method of MessageServiceImpl which should return a non-null Message Obj
@Test
public void createShouldReturnNotNullMessageObj(){

    // mocking save method to return the same Obj that was passed
    when(messageRepository.save(any(Message.class))).then(AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg());

    Message result = messageService.create(); 

    // This fails and displays "Wanted but not invoked: Actually, there were 
    // zero interactions with this mock" 
    verify(messageRepository).save(any(Message.class));

    Assert.assertNotNull(result);
}
```

I can't figure out why other mock services are working as expected but the repository does not get invoked. As a result, the Message Obj is returned as null from save(Message message) obj.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `@SpringBootTest(classes = Abc.class)`: it's a unit test, not an integration test.

Remove `@Autowired`: you're using constructor injection.

Remove `messageService = new MessageServiceImpl(messageRepository);`: the Mockito annotations do that for you, and since you have `initMocks()` **after** this instruction, `messageRepository` is still null at that point anyway.

Remove `RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`since you're calling `initMocks()` explicitly in your code.

Comment: I've made the changes, still the same result. I don't think I understand what you're pointing out at.

Comment: I've added one more thing you need to remove.

Comment: The tests still fail with the exact same error. Can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: Post a complete reproduction where we only have to copy and paste your code. When I do it your test passed. So there's something we don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `@InjectMocks` on your `messageService` variable. And the initialize it on the constructor itself.

Do one of those, not both, my guess is that's where your problem lies. The `@InjectMock` initializes your object and inject the mocks in for you. If you do that and initialize your object manually, results can be unpredictable.

Your wiring is also off, you are using constructor initialization but has the `@Autowired` annotation on the field, move it to the constructor.

You also have `SpringBootTest` annotation on top of your class, which is not necessary for a unit test.

Comment: Was playing around @InjectMocks and also doing it in setup to see if that might work. Keeping both makes no difference. It still fails

Comment: What happens when you fixes your wiring, removes @InjectMocks?

Comment: That was by mistake. I didn't have autowiring in my original code. I've fixed that here

Comment: Those were the only obvious mistakes I could see.

Comment: Removing @InjectMocks and instead initializing obj manually in setip also makes no difference, Still fails